# Flutter: remove all saved shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

I want to delete all saved shared preferences when the user taps on logout. Are there any ways to do this in a single shot without deleting one by one?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I use `shared_preferences` plugin:

In `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
```

And in dart file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
...
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.clear();
```

I think this is what you need

Comment: `preferences.clear();` does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: It can be if you're checking it right after `preferences.clear();`. I didn't mention, but it is an asynchronous operation, so, maybe you need to use `await preferences.clear();` and check after it

Comment: I did use `await`.

Comment: It's quite strange. I think you'd better create new question with detailed description of your problem and all that you've done to solve it.

Comment: Well that would be marked as duplicate of this question. ‍♂️

Comment: Not if you already tried correct answer to existing question and it didn't help. Just don't forget to mention this in new question with link to this

Comment: i hae one question, where sharedPreferenecs data is clear automatically? after each app restart?

Comment: Consider updating answer to "await preferences.clear();" please..

Comment: @Learner actually, it doesn't matter in this case if we don't need the result. `clear()` method will be launched without `await` too

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky true. But when test, sometimes i see mismatches...

Answer (score 44):

You can simply use `clear()` function with your variable it will clear all the shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.clear();
```

If you want to remove particular key value from shared preferences with key name you can do it like this way as follows.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.remove('KeyNameHere');
```

Answer (score 18):

try

```
final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await pref.clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try

```dart
prefManager = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefManager.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

To Clear Shared Preferences Data

1. You should import shared_preferences.dart
2. write this code into the logout button

   onPressed: () {
   SharedPreferences userData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await userData.clear();
   }

Answer (score 1):

To clear all shared preferences, try this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await pref.clear();
```

To clear particular key value, try this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await pref.remove('KeyNameHere');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.clear();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?